# MongoDB Index - Performance considerations on collections with high write-to-read ratio

Tags: mongodb, performance, indexing

I have a MongoDB Collection with around 100k inserts every day. Each document consumes around 1 MB space and has a lot of elements.

The Data is mainly stored for analytics purpose and read a couple times each day. I want to speed up the queries by adding indexes to a few fields which are usually used for filtering but stumpled accross this statement in the mongodb documentation:

> Adding an index has some negative performance impact for write operations. For collections with high write-to-read ratio, indexes are expensive since each insert must also update any indexes.
> [source](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-model-operations/#data-model-indexes)

I was wondering if this should bother me with 100k inserts vs. a couple of big read operations and if this would add a lot of overhead to the insert operations?

If yes, should i separete reads from writes in in separate collections and duplicate the data or are there any other solutions for this?

Comment: Can you share more about the usage of your read operation?(e.g. it's for batch reporting by week/month? Do the read operation have filtering such that it only requires a subset of the collection?...)

Comment: It´s meant for ad hoc querys for reporting via tableau which might fetch data for the last day or even a couple of months. The most common filer is by insert date greater than and there are other options like product.

Comment: Do you have any performance requirements for the read operation? If there is none, I think your approach for not adding an index would be best for improving the performance of insert operation. On the other hand, I would suggest you benchmark the operations to observe the actual performance. It would definitely help with your performance tuning task.

Comment: I´ve now added the index on the date field and I did add a huge performance boost on the reading querys whiche used this field for pre-filtering. I didn´t expirience any issues on the writing side. Thank you very much.